# TSQL update table using call for one stored procedure to another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure which returns the file size in bytes per input full file path string.

I want to write another wrapping stored procedure or function to update a table that has two columns. Column Full_Path (input for the stored procedure below) and column size (should be updated by the output from the procedure below). Basically I want to update the size column per each file (specified in the full path column) using the procedure below.

I am not sure how to do it. Please advise.

```
Create proc sp_get_file_size (@fileName varchar(200))
as

begin 
 declare @ntcmd varchar(200)
 declare @detailLine varchar(200)
 declare @pos1 int
 declare @pos2 int
 declare @size int

 set nocount on 

 Create table #res (line varchar(400))
 set @ntcmd = 'dir /-C ' + @fileName 
 insert #res exec xp_CmdShell @ntcmd 
 select @detailLine = line 
    from #res where rtrim(ltrim(line)) like '%bytes'

 -- if detail Line is null - return -1
 if isnull (@detailLine ,'*') = '*' return -1

-- get position of words bytes and File(s)
 set @pos1 = charindex ('bytes' ,lower(@detailLine))
 set @pos2 = charindex ('(s)' , lower(@detailLine))

-- extract the size value from the details Line
 set @size = convert (int, rtrim(ltrim( 
                       substring (@detailLine , @pos2+3,@pos1 - @pos2 - 4))))
 return (@size)
 set nocount off
end
go
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your stored procedure as scalar used-defined function that returns the size. Then you don't need a second stored procedure, a single update statement will do the trick:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Size = fn_get_file_size(Full_Path)
```

(note: you will need to use table variable instead of temp table `#res` since temp tables aren't allowed inside of UDFs)

Comment: nOTICE THE exec xp_CmdShell @ntcmd in the SP. I cannot call it in a function I think. I am getting errors that I cannot use insert exec in a function. Any workarounds?

Comment: I believe extended stored procedures can be called from UDF, have never tried it myself, but it should be possible. If it's not - you will have to resort to looping thru table (CURSOR oh well) and run your SP for every record individually. OR build a dynamic SQL with multiple calls to the SP and execute it in one go